# IMain.valueOfTerm only gets last value

Tags: scala

```
import scala.tools.nsc._
import scala.tools.nsc.interpreter._

val settings = new Settings
val n = new IMain(settings)

n.interpret("""
val y = 5
val x = 10
""")
println(n.valueOfTerm("y").get)

n.close()
```

I would expect that `println` would print `5`, the value of `y`. Instead it prints `10`, the value of `x`.

Now if I interpret this:

```
n.interpret("""
val y = 5
val x = 10
y
""")
```

It prints `5`, the value of `y`. Therefor I assume `valueOfTerm` returns only the last mentioned value. Isn't it intended to return the requested value? Anyone can reproduce this? Or is something wrong with my code?

I used Scala 2.10.3 for this setup. [Scala Doc IMain](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs-2.10.x/compiler/index.html#scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain)

Comment: Asking scala-user: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-user/po4weZ6Ql7E

Comment: Works on 2.11, not on 2.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I can confirm that it works as you expect on 2.11, but as you describe on 2.10.

However, I can't promise that I can backport the change.  Well, I'll see if it's a quick fix.

Otherwise, the method is especially badly named on 2.10.

Comment: If you can add this as quickfix it may be available with scala 2.10.4? That would be nice!